# Using package aslagle:reactive-table with X-editable

Tags: meteor, x-editable

I'm using reactive table package from aslagle in my app and I want to create in-line editing, I searched and I found that there's x-editable package for Meteor, so how can I use aslagle:reactive-table package with workman:x-editable-reactive-template package?

I tried this:

**Reactive-Table settings:**

```
  tableSettings: function () {
      return {
          collection: fLogCollection,
          rowsPerPage: 10,
          showFilter: true,
          fields: [
            { key: 'name', label: 'Name'},
            { key: 'amount',
              label: 'Amount',
              tmpl: Template.xEditableAmount
            },
            { key: 'cashFrom', label: 'Cash From'},
            { key: 'dateIs', label: 'Date', sortOrder: 0, sortDirection: 'descending'},
            { key: 'controls', label: 'Controls', fn: function () {
              return new Spacebars.SafeString(
                "<button class='editFlog'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> </button>"+
                "<button class='delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> </button>"
                ); } },
            { key: 'createdAt', label: 'createdAt', hidden: true },
          ],
      };
  },
```

**xEditableAmount template**:

```
<template name="xEditableAmount">
      <a href="#" id="amount" data-type="text" class="editable" data-title="Enter the new amount">{{amount}}</a>
</template>
```

This code to get the **x-editable** rendered:

```
Template.fLog.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.editable').editable({
      success: function (response, newValue) {
         if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg; //msg will be shown in editable form
         else Meteor.call('flog.edit2', this._id, newValue);
      },
    });
});
```

I succeeded in making x-editable render but

**I failed at getting the field updated with the new value in collection...**

Comment: Are you stuck on using x-editable? It is fairly straight forward to create an inline editable table using reactive table.

Comment: actually I'm stuck at finding a way to make x-editable package work with the reactive-table package

Comment: For further readers: X-editable seems to be abandoned now https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/610

Answer (score 0):

You can inject templates into fields which makes it convenient to add almost anything you want.

Template helper:

```
tableSettings: function() {
    return {
        collection: foo,
        fields: [
            {
                key: 'foo_1',
                label: 'Foo 1',
                tmpl: Template.foo1,
            },
            {
                key: 'foo_2',
                label: 'Foo 2',
                tmpl: Template.foo2,
            },
            {
                key: 'foo_2',
                label: 'Foo 2',
                tmpl: Template.foo2,
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

In foo2 helper (copied directly from [workman/x-editable-reactive-template atmosphere page](https://atmospherejs.com/workman/x-editable-reactive-template)):

```
Template.foo2.helpers({
    onSuccess: function () {
        var id = this._id;
        return function (res, val) {
            MyColl.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { prop: val } });
        }
    }
});
```

In your Templates:

```
<template name='table>
    {{> reactiveTable settings=tableSettings}}`
</template>

<template name='foo1'>
    <!-- Any html (below pasted from docs (link at bottom of post)-->
    <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
</template>

<template name='foo2'>
    {{> xEditable type="text" success=onSuccess placement="right" }} <!-- put your workman:x-editable-reactive-template here -->
</template>
```

This should get you pointed in the right direction.

https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

Comment: Dear, have you ever tried to work with "workman:x-editable-reactive-template"? it seems to be easier to work with

Comment: I have not used workman:x-editable-reactive-template. Though It looks fairly straight forward. I've updated the answer to add an workman:x-editable-reactive-template example.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, I updated the question with the code that got me close to make it work, I got it rendered but I failed at updating the collection with new value.. any suggestions? @Jeremiah

Comment: Is there an error message? Try some troubleshooting. Put console.logs in problem areas so you can see and understand what is happening.

Comment: there's no error massage of any kind, the submit button just do nothing

Comment: Any luck with the `cosole.log` troubleshooting? Start peppering your code with those.

Comment: I figured that x-editable package is abandoned 2 years ago and it seems that the package itself is no longer workable on newer version of meteor, so I gave up on it and on reactive table itself because I couldn't find a way to do "editing"... I guess I'll doing it all manually